# Excel VBA assigning cells to cells (inserting cell value to each row according to another worksheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets in Excel, the first contains list of companies (row: company name, city, street, phone number, email, etc.), the second sheet contains list of all cities in a given country with the districts (row: city, district). I need to add name of appropriate district to each row in the first sheet, according to the data from the second worksheet.

Please suggest some solution. Thanks.

The data structure of the sheets are the following:

**Sheet 1** (simplified):

**Company name | Street name | City | Phone number**

A-B Finance Ltd | Carl-Zeiss-Strasse 5 | Alsdorf | +49 18 4514 8451

LR Munchen Ltd | Christ-König-Strasse 85 | Monschau | +49 18 0181 1584

Finance Master Ltd | Castorstrasse 2 | Herrieden | +49 15 8451 2154

**Sheet 2:**

**City | District**

Alsdorf | Aachen

Herrieden | Ansbach

Monschau | Aachen

As a **result** I need to get this in **Sheet 1:**

**Company name | Street name | City | Phone number | District**

A-B Finance Ltd | Carl-Zeiss-Strasse 5 | Alsdorf | +49 18 4514 8451 | Aachen

LR Munchen Ltd | Christ-König-Strasse 85 | Monschau | +49 18 0181 1584 | Aachen

Finance Master Ltd | Castorstrasse 2 | Herrieden | +49 15 8451 2154 | Ansbach

Comment: I have basic VBA skills, that's why I need your help.

Comment: You can do that easily with Vlookup, if there is a common index/information column between the sheets. Of course, depending on the number of rows, using VBA, looping though rows (or even an array) would be more efficient. IF you are a beginner, use the macro recorder and do it for some rows, that might give you a basic understanding of what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to match the data in both sheets, e.g. a list of streets for each district.
If this information is not provided then no program can help you.

As soon as you have this, the code should be straight forward:

1. loop through each row in first sheet
2. match information from sheets (this information is missing in your explanation)
3. add information from second sheet to first sheet

I can add some code if you provide more information about your data structure.